# how to compile multi-folder Fortran Project having interfaces, modules and subroutines

Tags: module, fortran, gfortran, subroutine

I am new to Fortran. I am working on a research project where I am using an open source project that has several files distributed in multiple folders. i found the dependency of each programs but could not figure out how to compile them.

I have source code distributed in three folders.
a)modules
b)interfaces
c)subroutines

I would like to run a program named as 'Main.f90' in subroutines folder, this program has dependency of source codes from modules and interfaces folders.

I am using eclipse for folder structure and makefile to compile.

Any help with this is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I followed the answer posted by @MBR and @Stefan, for some reason VPATH did not able to find programs in source code so I explicitly gave path to those source folder in my *Makefile*.  below is my make file script.

```
    .PHONY: Mopac_exe clean

    # Change this line if you are using a different Fortran compiler
    FORTRAN_COMPILER = gfortran
    SRC = src

    #make main program 
    Mopac_exe: subroutines mopac.o
        $(FORTRAN_COMPILER) mopac.o *.o -O2 -g  -o bin/Mopac_exe  -I Modules/

    #compile all the subroutines
    subroutines: interfaces
        $(FORTRAN_COMPILER) -c $(SRC)/subroutines/*.F90 -J Modules/Subroutines/ -I Modules/

    #compiles all the interfaces
    interfaces: modules
        $(FORTRAN_COMPILER) -c $(SRC)/interfaces/*.f90 -J Modules/


     # build all the modules and generate .mod file in Modules directory
     modules: build_vast_kind
        $(FORTRAN_COMPILER) -c $(SRC)/modules/*.f90 -J Modules/
        $(FORTRAN_COMPILER) -c $(SRC)/modules/*.F90 -J Modules/

    # compile vastkind.f90 files and generates the .mod file in Modules directory.Every other Modules and interfaces are dependent on this. 
    build_vast_kind:clean
       $(FORTRAN_COMPILER) -c $(SRC)/modules/vastkind.f90 -J Modules/

    clean:
       rm -f bin/Mopac_exe *.mod
       rm -f Modules/*.mod
       rm -f *.o
```

I compiled all the modules and placed in Modules directory of root Folder.
All compilation goes well. I get error when I build the executable. I get following error.

```
    gfortran mopac.o *.o -O2 -g     -o bin/Mopac_exe  -I Modules/
    mopac.o: In function `main':
    mopac.F90:(.text+0x27c1): multiple definition of `main'
    mopac.o:mopac.F90:(.text+0x27c1): first defined here
    getdat.o: In function `getdat_':
    getdat.F90:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `iargc_'
    getdat.F90:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `getarg_'
    symr.o: In function `symr_':
    symr.F90:(.text+0xd3f): undefined reference to `symp_'
    writmo.o: In function `writmo_':
    writmo.F90:(.text+0x20c2): undefined reference to `volume_'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [Mopac_exe] Error 1
```

`iargc_' is being used in 'getdat file and iargc is already compiled. why there is error while making the executable saying undefined reference? what am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

You can do a Makefile which looks like that

```
F90=gfortran
FFLAGS = -O0
VPATH = modules:interfaces:subroutines:
MODOBJ = module1.o module2.o ...

your_executable: $(MODOBJ) main.o
        $(F90) main.o -o your_executable
%.o:%.f90
        $(F90) $(FFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
```

`VPATH` is the paths of the directories where your Makefile will look for source files, so if you compile your source in the root directory of `modules/`, `interfaces/` and `subroutines/`, you just have to set up `VPATH` like that.

If you have many objects and you don't want to write everything by hand, you can retrieve them using the following trick

```
F90 = gfortran
FFLAGS = -O0
VPATH = modules:interfaces:subroutines
SRCOBJ = $(wildcard modules/*f90)
MODOBJ = $(SRCOBJ:.f90=.o)

your_executable: $(MODOBJ) main.o
        $(F90) main.o -o your_executable
%.o:%.f90
        $(F90) $(FFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
```

The `wildcard` command in a Makefile allows you to use a joker `*`; then you just have to say that in the strings you will retrieve in `$(SRCOBJ)`, you want to substitute `.f90` by `.o` to get the filenames of your modules.

Comment: Thank you MBR
Your makefile makes lots of sense to me. I tried to write but could not get through running the program. The problem is that I have all the interfaces created for several subroutines and those interfaces are listed in Main.f90 program using "USE" keyword. Similarly modules are also used in Main.f90 using "USE" keyword.

Since the there are large files, how I can dynamically include and link them rather than listing each file as you have mentioned in your Answer such as 
MODOBJ = module1.o module2.o ...

Answer (score 3):

You can create your Makefiles as usual. The biggest problem should be the `.mod` files. The easiest solution to this problem is to create a separate folder, where these files are stored and searched for.

This can be achieved with the `-J` and the `-module` flags for `gfortran` and `ifort`, respectively.