# gfortran: compile source codes from hierarchically dependent subroutine files

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I want to compile `main.f90`, and it depends on three subroutines in separate files. For the third subroutine, it also has three sub_subroutines.

2. `sub1.f`
3. `sub2.f`
4. `sub3_main.f sub3_sub1.f sub3_sub2.f sub3_sub3.f`

Run the following code would produce a long error message as below.

`gfortran main.f90 sub1.f sub2.f sub3_main.f sub3_sub1.f sub3_sub2.f sub3_sub3.f -o- test.exe`

I searched and found that I may need flag `-c`, but I am not sure about the order of compiling, and then how to link object files into a standalone program. Or it is related to this question: [how to compile multi-folder Fortran Project having interfaces, modules and subroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463947/how-to-compile-multi-folder-fortran-project-having-interfaces-modules-and-subro).

Thanks in advance!

```
test.exe: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
test.exe: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
test.exe: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
test.exe:(.rodata+0x4): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
test.exe: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
test.exe:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_fp_hw'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
test.exe: In function `main':
(.text+0x399): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/ccwQ3UVQ.o:main.f90:(.text+0x20ee): first defined here
test.exe: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of `__DTOR_END__'
test.exe:(.dtors+0x4): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in test.exe(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do either:

```
gfortran -c sub1.f
gfortran -c sub2.f
gfortran -c sub3_main.f sub3_sub1.f sub3_sub2.f sub3_sub3.f
gfortran sub1.o sub2.o sub3_main.o sub3_sub1.o sub3_sub2.o sub3_sub3.o  main.f90 -o text.exe
```

or

```
gfortran sub1.f sub2.f sub3_main.f sub3_sub1.f sub3_sub2.f sub3_sub3.f main.f90 -o text.exe
```

You should only have one program and any number of proceduers (subroutines and functions).  The above assumes that sub3_main is a procedures and that your program in in main.f90.

Comment: Thanks @M. S. B.! You are right, `sub3_main.f` is a procedure that depends on `sub3_sub1.f sub3_sub2.f sub3_sub3.f`. But I have no idea why both approaches would produce the same errors as I confronted before.

Comment: If you still get the same errors, I guess you need to show us something of the code. Do you really have one program in all of the files? Do you use variables called main somewhere?

Comment: Thanls @haraldkl! I only have one program in `main.f90`, and there is no variable called `main` in all of the files. I tested each group of subroutines with the following code, and they can work well. `gfortran test_sub1.f90 sub1.f -o- test_sub1.exe`, `gfortran test_sub2.f90 sub2.f -o- test_sub2.exe`, `gfortran test_sub3.f90 sub3_main.f sub3_sub1.f sub3_sub2.f sub3_sub3.f -o- test_sub3.exe`. Sorry the source codes are a mess and I can only provide the abstract file names.

Comment: Do you have a `program` statement in more than one of the files?  Otherwise how could you make an executable from various subsets of the files?  There should only be one main program.

Comment: For the question, I only have one `program` statement in `main.f90`. To test the subroutines, as I mentioned in the above comment, I used `program` statements in `test_sub1.f90 test_sub2.f90 test_sub3.f90` before.

Comment: Thank all of you! I solved this problem by integrating `sub3_main.f sub3_sub1.f sub3_sub2.f sub3_sub3.f` into a single file. The previous errors may be caused by prior `.o` or `.exe` files.