# Fortran 95 - How to automatically find modules used in the main program when compiling it

Tags: module, fortran, build-process

I have made my first Fortran programme mainp.f95, with two separate files mfun.f95 and mbisection.f95, which are the modules used in mainp.f95.

I have found on Internet 2 ways to compile it:

*First way*

```
gfortran mfun.95 mbisection.f95 mainp.f95
```

Then a.out and two files.mod are created, being a.out the executable.

*Second way*

```
gfortran -c mfun.95 -o mfun.o
gfortran -c mbisection.f95 -o mbisection.o
```

then two files.o and two files.mod are created.

```
gfortran mainp.f95 mbisection.o mfun.o
```

then the a.out file is created.

I do not know if they are optima, but they worked.

*Question*

However, imagine that I do not have 2 modules, but 20 modules.

Should I write each module in the gfortran command, or is there a way to "compile only the main programme", automatically adding the required .o and .mod files? (providing that all the files are in the same folder, therefore it is easy to "search the modules")

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a project grows from "Hello World" to something more complicated, it is time to switch from direct command line compilation to a [build automation tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software). There are many possibilities how to simplify building of large projects, for example [makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefiles.html), [Microsoft Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio), [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/).

Comment: There are even Qs & As here on SO, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463947 , which go some way to answering the question.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you, that was exactly the answers I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at these links. However, I noticed that they are all designed for C or Java. Searching through forums, including the thread which High Performance Mark wrote, I noticed that "automatic build" is no other thing than writing all the commands that I would write in Terminal, but in a file, and then run the file.

I thought it was something more... automatic (For example, it looks for you the files which are dependent (like modules which are in other files), and compiles it in "a recommended order", with just one click).

I think that this MUST exist somewhere on Internet, but since I have not found it, I have decided to create my own automated compiler. And since you have helped me, I share my compiler with you (you would see it very basic, with no compiling options, but for me the advanced options (so far) are irrelevant and, to be honest, unknown).

My compiler is a fortran-written file which works as follows:

First stage:
It takes a fortran.f95 file, then reads its second line. If it finds a 'use', then it copies the used module. This process repeats until all modules are found.

Second stage:
Then it opens each module, in order to search submodules. The process is the same: It reads the second line, and if it finds a 'use', then it copies the submodule. Then the third... until it finds no 'use' word.

Third stage:
Then it copies all the submodules in a character array (here it is assumed that submodules cannot use modules, which is a bad point, thinking in modules containing PI, E, and so on), and it searches all modules which are the same, in order to compile each module only once.

Fourth stage:
Then it writes the final command to be written in terminal: gfortran (list of submodules.f95) (list of modules.f95) main.f95

The file extension '.f95' is a word initializated at the beginning of the file, so it can be changed easily to 'f90' or whatever.

I do not see any button to add my code, so I copy it down here, in case anyone wants to use it. It works for me.
The files must be in the same folder. I hope that answering me and posting my compiler do not violate stackexchange's rules, my intention is to help and not to disturb :)

```
program compilador

IMPLICIT NONE
CHARACTER (LEN=18),DIMENSION(100) :: matvec
INTEGER,DIMENSION(10) :: m,proh
CHARACTER (LEN=18) :: hayuse
CHARACTER (LEN=18),DIMENSION(10) :: modulos
CHARACTER (LEN=18),DIMENSION(10,10) :: submodulos
CHARACTER (LEN=4) :: ext='.f95'
CHARACTER (LEN=2) :: for
INTEGER :: n,j,i=1,t,total,error_de_apertura,error_de_lectura,error_de_escritura 
LOGICAL :: cond OPEN(60,FILE='main.f95',STATUS='OLD',ACTION='READ',& 
IOSTAT=error_de_apertura)
IF (error_de_apertura>0) STOP 'main.f95 NO ABIERTO'
OPEN (70,FILE='comando.txt',STATUS='NEW',ACTION='WRITE',& IOSTAT=error_de_apertura)
IF (error_de_apertura>0) STOP 'comando.txt NO ABIERTO'
DO
if (i==1) then
READ(60,'(/,A3,X1A)',IOSTAT=error_de_lectura) hayuse,modulos(i)
else
READ(60,'(A3,X1A)',IOSTAT=error_de_lectura) hayuse,modulos(i)
endif
if (.not.(hayuse=='use')) exit modulos(i)
(len_trim(modulos(i))+1:len_trim(modulos(i))+4)='.f95' WRITE(*,*) hayuse,modulos(i) 
i=i+1
end do

n=i-1
IF (n>=1) THEN

!MODULOS DE MODULOS DO i=1,n

OPEN(30+i,FILE=modulos(i),STATUS='OLD',ACTION='READ',& IOSTAT=error_de_apertura)
IF (error_de_apertura>0) then
WRITE(*,*) modulos(i)//' NO ABIERTO'
STOP
endif
j=1
DO
if (j==1) then
READ(30+i,'(/,A3,X1A)',IOSTAT=error_de_lectura) hayuse,submodulos(i,j)
else
READ(30+i,'(A3,X1A)',IOSTAT=error_de_lectura) hayuse,submodulos(i,j)
endif
if (error_de_lectura>0) then WRITE (*,*) 'Error de lectura en ',modulos(i)
endif
if (.not.(hayuse=='use')) exit
submodulos(i,j)(len_trim(submodulos(i,j))+1:len_trim(submodulos(i,j))+5)='.f95'
WRITE(*,*) hayuse,submodulos(i,j)
j=j+1
end do
m(i)=j-1
end do
endif


total=1
Do i=1,n
Do j=1,m(i)
matvec(total)=submodulos(i,j)
total=total+1
end do
end do
total=total-1

!BUSQUEDA
Do i=1,total
Do j=i+1,total
if (matvec(i)==matvec(j)) then
matvec(j)=' '
endif
end do
end do

WRITE(*,*) matvec

if (n>=1) then
WRITE(70,*,IOSTAT=error_de_escritura) 'gfortran ',matvec(1:total),modulos(1:n),' main.f95'
else
WRITE(70,*,IOSTAT=error_de_escritura) 'gfortran ','main.f95'
endif
if (error_de_escritura>0) STOP 'Error de escritura final'

END PROGRAM compilador
```

Comment: Don't let me, or anyone else, stop you trying to write an automated build system, it looks like a fun project.  But you're wrong to have noticed that the links provided above all refer to Java or C; the link I provided is specifically about using Make for Fortran programs.  And the Internet is awash with material on using Cmake and Make for Fortran; if you have Intel Fortran on MS Windows then Visual Studio provides a good choice of build system.  Personally I think your time would be better spent learning Make than writing your own replacement, it's an extremely non-trivial task.  Good luck.

Comment: Okey, Mark. I will do it! Thank you very much for your advise. I just tried to use some, and since I only saw C and java... thanks for the info, I will spend more time trying to learn 'make'!!!