# Fortran: makefile with multiple directories

Tags: makefile, dependencies, fortran, gfortran

I have a large fortran project like this:

project

|-\bin

|-\obj

|-\src

|--\fortran

|---\common

|---\prePro

I am trying to build a makefile like [this one:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463947/how-to-compile-multi-folder-fortran-project-having-interfaces-modules-and-subro)

```
F90 = gfortran
FFLAGS = -O3
VPATH = modules:interfaces:subroutines
SRCOBJ = $(wildcard modules/*f90)
MODOBJ = $(SRCOBJ:.f90=.o)

your_executable: $(MODOBJ) main.o
    $(F90) main.o -o your_executable
%.o:%.f90
    $(F90) $(FFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
```

that lies on the bin directory. For now I came up with this:

```
FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -O3
VPATH = ../src/fortran/common:../src/fortran/prePro:
SRCOBJ = $(wildcard ../src/fortran/common/*.f90) $(wildcard ../src/fortran/prePro/*.f90)
MODOBJ = $(SRCOBJ:.f90=.o)

all: prePro

prePro: $(MODOBJ) prePro.o
    $(FC) prePro.o -o prePro

%.o %.mod:%.f90
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
```

However this don't work because most of my files are modules and they depend on each other.
Adding the dependencies manually fix the issue, i.e.:

```
../src/fortran/common/common_routines.o: ../src/fortran/common/types.o ../src/fortran/common/global.o

../src/fortran/common/global.o: ../src/fortran/common/types.o
etc...
```

Is there any easier (shorter) way to fix the dependency issues?

Bonus question: How can I trow the objects and modules in a obj folder and link the program from there?

Comment: There are build systems which can automatically solve dependencies for Fortran, but make is not among them.

Comment: Compilers may offer dependency list generation.  Is this the sort of thing you mean?